# smtplib.SMTP('smtp.office365.com', 587) hanging on Windows Server 2012

Tags: python-3.x, smtplib

I have written a very basic python code to send email and it works on my local Windows 10 machine however doesn't work on another machine which has Windows Server 2012. So I started investigating and identified that the code is not going past **smtplib.SMTP('smtp.office365.com', 587)** line. Next I tried on command line by typing below -

```
import smtplib
s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.office365.com', 587)
```

and it never goes to the next line and freezes.... waited for more than 15 mins

To ensure that 587 port is not blocked, I did below on admin command prompt -

`telnet smtp.office365.com 587`

and it returns back with blank screen without any errors so I am assuming that firewall is NOT blocking the incoming port.

I am testing on Python version 3.8.5

I am stuck at this point and searched all over the place but couldn't find any solution.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.